# How to Dynamically Change "a href" Link on A HTML "rect" Tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I'm trying to recreate circle navigation on webpage using this reference: https://codepen.io/gzuzkstro/pen/oemMyN

---

But, I got confused about the link reference at "Learn more" button on each of the navigation. There are 7 navigations and just 1 tag of "rect" to generate "Learn more" button. When I put "a href" tag, it worked but all of the buttons reference the same URL. "rect" tag presents at line 320 of the HTML file.

---

I put the "a href" tag like this

```
<a href="index.html"><rect data-url="/industries" id="learn-more" x="280" y="250" width="90" height="30" /></a>
```

and it all worked for all the buttons on different navigation. How to dynamically change the link reference on each navigation of the "Learn more" button?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Since I've obviously missed the `rect` part of the question, here's a new answer. The old answer remains below as a reference.

**NEW ANSWER:**

Short answer is you don't. Rect is not an anchor, so whether you add a href attribute to it or not, will not have any effect. The simplest way to solve this is to store the target URL in a variable that is accessible to the click handler you bind to your rect element.

In the click handler for the circles, you update the value of this variable, and then in the click handler for the `rect`, you use the variable. It will be a global variable, though, so I can already see someone posting a letter of protest below in the comments.

If you don't like global vars, you can set a data attribute on the `rect`, and read that in the click handler.

In relation to your actual code, you have several `g.service` tags that user click to select a service. Then you have a single `rect` that represents the "Learn more" link. When user clicks on the `g.service`, that's when you set the target URL according to one of the solutions noted above (either as a global variable, or an attribute on the `rect`). Finally, when user clicks on the `rect`, you then take them to the target URL.

Now while this should work, it's a bad idea. Using elements other than an anchor tag for links is bad UX. For example, users cannot do the usual right-click to copy the link or open it in a new tab, etc. I recommend you change the design and use the anchor tag. The portion in the middle does not look like it needs to be SVG.

**OLD ANSWER:**

Since your code is quite complicated and I did not feel like going through everything to figure out what you have to fix, I'm going to give you a general idea of what you need to do. I see you use jQuery there, so the example is using jQuery.

```js
var learnMore = $('.learnmore');

$('.buttons').on('click', '.topic', function (event) {
  var url = $(event.target).data('url');
  learnMore.attr('href', url);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a class="learnmore" href="#foo">Learn more</a>
</div>

<div class="buttons">
  <button class="topic" data-url="#foo">Foo</button>
  <button class="topic" data-url="#bar">Bar</button>
  <button class="topic" data-url="#baz">Baz</button>
</div>
```

We have a basic HTML structure where we have one anchor that has the `href` attribute we want to manipulate. We also have several interactive elements (in the example it's `button`) which will set the `href` when clicked.

The idea is to handle the click event, read the `data-url` attribute, and then use that attribute to set the `href` value of the anchor.

Comment: I noticed that in the javascript line 161, class_index variable is the index of the navigations. I added console log to see the value of that variable. And it changes when I clicked on different navigation. index 0 to 6. How to use that for "Learn-more" buttons in my case?

Comment: in your solution there are 3 button tags, so you can put different anchor on them. But, in the source code that I provided there is just 1 tag of rect for all the buttons. How do I put different anchor on them?

Comment: In your example, I see a few `g.service` tags. That's where you need to put the target URL because that's where the user will click. When they click on `g.service`, then you change the variable that holds the URL that user should reach when clicking the `rect`, or something else (see answer).